# How do I control the pop up information when hovering over an MFC application Icon?

Tags: windows, mfc

I have an MFC application I am developing for Windows 10, using Visual Studio 2022.  When I hover over the icon of the executable (whether on the Desktop or in a File Explorer Window), I would like to see a set of informational details related to the file, such as Version, Date last modified, File Description, etc.

How / where do I control what is displayed when I hover the mouse over the executable icon in Windows? Abd how do I enable the pop-up info box if it is not currently enabled??

Comment: Set the information in the VERSIONINFO resource in your resource file. You can use the resource editor or edit the .rc file manually.

Comment: *"How / where do I control what is displayed"* - You don't. That decision has been made for you by the Shell. All you can do is supply the information the Shell is using, such as the version information resource.